# Rejected promise not working with ui-grid-row-edit and LoopBack AngularJS SDK

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-ui-grid, loopbackjs, strongloop

The rowSave function of rowEdit is working fine when success (it is saving in DB), but when it fails it keeps printing 'success'. Ive spent two days trying to solve it, learned a lot, but I am still not able to throw an error when the DB is offline.

Edit: The error message does appear when the server is down, but not when the DB is down.

If tried to follow

[UI GRID Row Edit Feature](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/205_row_editable)

[AngularJSJavaScriptSDK-Update](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK#AngularJSJavaScriptSDK-Update)

```
    function ApropiacionController($scope, $q, $log, Presupuesto) {
    var vm          = this;
    vm.vigenciaGrid = {};

    vm.vigenciaGrid = {
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
            gridApi.rowEdit.on.saveRow($scope, $scope.saveRow);
        }
    };

    $scope.saveRow = function (rowEntity) {
        var promise = Presupuesto
            .prototype$updateAttributes(
            {vigencia: rowEntity.vigencia},
            rowEntity,
            function (response) {
                $log.log('exito');
                $log.log(response);
            },
            function (response) {
                $log.error('error');
                $log.error(response);
            })
            .$promise;
        $scope.gridApi.rowEdit.setSavePromise(rowEntity, promise);
    };
}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: It's a little hard to tell exactly what is going on based on the code, but typically you get an ERROR response when the connection fails (ie your server is down) but you get success when it is able to connect. Your service will have to return an Http type error code upon a successful connection but unable to update the database and then you can act on it in the "success" block of your promise based on the response.status code returned.

Comment: Hi. Nothing in the response shows the update has failed. Checked the response with and without mongodb available and the object has the same properties and values.

Comment: You are going to have to return the Http code yourself. I don't know what "updateAttributes" does, but in that server-side code I would assume you connect to a database and try and update records. You will need to do something like - try and update records in DB. If failure then respond with an HttpStatus of NOT_FOUND or CONFLICT or whatever code you want.

Comment: I hope I could use the AngularSDK without going deeper for now.

Comment: You're assuming Ajax knows the difference between being unable to make a connection and being able to make a connection but being unable to update data in a database. All AJAX knows is that it was successful in reaching the end point of the URL you supplied and thus it knows the difference between a success and a failure. What happens at that end point and what is considered a "success" or "failure" is up to the end point, not AJAX.

Comment: You are right. But I was not assuming AJAX knows the difference, I was assuming the framework did.
I solved it making a little FindOne query in the promise to check Db connectivity. Definitely the framework notices when it doesnt receive data at all.